# Using moment in a JavaScript loop to collect every 7th day from a date 3 months back from a given date

Tags: javascript, loops, date, momentjs

Given a *startdate* (any date of the year), I need to go back 3 months in time and collect every 7th date up to and including the *startdate*. So far I have this loop which uses [momentjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment)

```
const date = new Date('2021-06-06T00:00:00.000Z');

for(var m = moment(date).subtract(3, 'months'); m.isSameOrBefore(date); m.add(7, 'days')) {
  console.log(m.format('YYYY-MM-DD'))
}
```

Which returns:

```
2021-03-06
2021-03-13
2021-03-20
2021-03-27
2021-04-03
2021-04-10
2021-04-17
2021-04-24
2021-05-01
2021-05-08
2021-05-15
2021-05-22
2021-05-29
2021-06-05
```

The problem is I want the loop to end on the given *startdate*

So if given the date 2021-06-06 in the example above, I want my end result to be:

```
2021-03-07
2021-03-14
2021-03-21
2021-03-28
2021-04-04
2021-04-11
2021-04-18
2021-04-25
2021-05-02
2021-05-09
2021-05-16
2021-05-23
2021-05-30
2021-06-06
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Since you actually want to get the result that you basically already have at hand - why not add a single day to the initial date before the loop starts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that's the case I would instead begin from the `startDate` instead.

So, basically `loop` starts from 2021-06-06 and subtract 7 days.
Set a `threshhold` date to compare, `moment(date).subtract(3, 'months')` in this case
and breaks the loop when `currentDate` is before `threshhold`.

```
const date = new Date('2021-06-06T00:00:00.000Z');
function getDateList(currentDate){
    currentDate = moment(currentDate)
    let result = [currentDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD')]
    let threshhold = moment(currentDate).subtract(3,'month')
    while(threshhold.isBefore(currentDate)){
        let nextCycle = currentDate.subtract(7,'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD')
        if(threshhold.isBefore(nextCycle))
            result.push(nextCycle)
    }
    return result
}
console.log(getDateList(date))
//Output:
[
  '2021-06-06', '2021-05-30',
  '2021-05-23', '2021-05-16',
  '2021-05-09', '2021-05-02',
  '2021-04-25', '2021-04-18',
  '2021-04-11', '2021-04-04',
  '2021-03-28', '2021-03-21',
  '2021-03-14', '2021-03-07'
]
```

There should be a cleaner way to write the code, didn't have time to clean up the code, feel free to edit the code.

***Suggestion: `momentjs` is depreciated, use `dayjs` instead.